# Is there a way to work around company authenticated proxy issues in Robolectric during Android unit testing?

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm writing unit tests in Android using Robolectric but facing an issue because of my company's authenticated proxy. When running tests, Robolectric attempts to download a Jar file during its initial startup, but fails because it can't get through the proxy authentication. Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
ERROR: Failed to fetch maven artifact org.robolectric:android-all-instrumented:13-robolectric-9030017-i4
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL
```

To solve this, I tried to add the proxy settings to build.gradle like so:

```
systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.proxy.host', project.findProperty("systemProp.https.proxyHost")
systemProperty 'robolectric.dependency.proxy.port', project.findProperty("systemProp.https.proxyPort")
```

However, this hasn't resolved the issue. I believe the error occurs because the proxy needs authentication.

Is there a way to make Robolectric aware of the proxy settings including the authentication? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.